# How to make page to jump to beginning of section after expander box is closed?

Tags: jquery, html, expander

The page I'm referencing is here:

http://jjnursingnotes.com/NOV12/

JQuery page is located here:

http://jjnursingnotes.com/NOV12/jquery.expander.js

After you click "Read More," what I would like to happen is for the page to jump to the heading ( **<h1>** ) or the beginning of the div layer ( **<div class="expander" id="sect##">** ) at the beginning of the section once you click "Read Less." Currently, the code for the "Read Less" button appears as follows:

```
      if ( o.userCollapse && !$this.find(o.lessSelector).length ) {
        $this
        .find(detailSelector)
        .append('<br><br><span class="' + o.lessClass + '">' + o.userCollapsePrefix + '<a href="#">' + o.userCollapseText + '</a></span><br><br>');
      }
```

My headings all have names assigned directly before (001, 002, etc.), and my guess would be to simply add #001, #002 etc. to the link in the JQ code. Problem is that this script defines every "Read Less" button on the page, so that variable would need to be different for each button. Am I on the right track, or is there a more efficient way to do this?

Thank you in advance. I am clearly a novice in all things JS and JQuery!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('.expander .read-more').click(function(e){
 $('html,body').animate({ scrollTop: $(e.target).closest('.expander').offset().top}, "slow");
})
```

there you go :)

Comment: by the way, you don't need "a names" for this, hope you like the anim

Comment: Thanks! "read-more" needs to be changed to "read-less" but otherwise this is the kind of solution I was looking for. One tiny issue, however, is that after clicking "read less" and the animation happens, the page won't let you scroll again for about a second or two. Any reason this might be happening?

Comment: Nevermind - I figured it out. Replaced ('html,body') with  ('html:not(:animated),body:not(:animated)'). Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `<a href="#">` why not just use `<a href="#sect##">`.  Then "Read Less" will work without any JS